# HP2035 printer prints gibberish

Tags: printing, network-printer, print-server

**Issue**

We have HP2035 on our network that for no apparent reason, on its own accord will print this gibberish:

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

**Additional Background**

Now, it'll print other documents just fine, it's just between the print jobs it'll print those gibberish pages.  The print queue is complete empty, when that happens.

**Setup**

It is running on print server Windows 2008 R2.  It is a PCL driver and up-to-date.

**What was done**

I restarted the print spooler as well as the server (stop and start, emptying the *%windir%\System32\spool\PRINTERS*).  Checked for to make sure the driver is up-to-date.  I checked the settings on the printer as well and nothing jumped out.

**Help!**

So, please, help!  I have seen someone suggesting installing PS driver instead or uninstalling and reinstalling drivers, I really would do as a total last ditch effort as it's a remote site and I might have to deal it individual drivers as well, it'll be a big pain, but I will do it if I have to.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gibberish print job could actually be spooled from another PC with the wrong drivers.  When a print job is created, the **local** drivers generate the data to be sent to the spooler on the print server, and not the drivers installed on the **print server**.

You'll have to see what clients are pointing to this print server, which might be challenging.  But you do have a hint -- the client has the PCL driver.

Comment: It might be problematic as it's also a DC...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see ([here](http://www8.hp.com/emea_africa/en/products/printers/product-detail.html?oid=3662038#!tab=specs) and [here](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-laserjet-p2035/specs/)), the 2035 supports PCL5E. PCL-XL (i.e. PCL6) does not seem to be supported - which is why you are getting that garbage. However, when I look for the drivers [here](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=3662026&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4022), only a GDI driver is available - and none at all for Server 2008.

Someone has a PCL6 driver installed, and you'll need to replace it with the correct driver. If the printer is networked, the PCs can print direct to it, bypassing the server.

Comment: That second paragraph--I was thinking that too. Looks like someone's printing directly, not to the queue. There might be multiple people/PCs bypassing the queue, and it would be one of those that's the offending machine.